# VSCode for MacOS creates backup files with tilde

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode v1.84.2 for MacOS. Every time I save a file, it creates a backup in the same folder with a tilde (~) appended, e.g. `filename.txt` gets a backup named `filename.txt~`.

I found this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/extra-files-with-tilde-character-appended/914282, but it seems to really be for Visual Studio. It references settings I can't find in my version of VSCode.

I would either like VSCode to stop creating these `filename.txt~` backup files or put them in some location other than where the original files exist. How do I do this?

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.